# Convergence of this series: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\Big(\frac{2x}{x+(n+5)^6}\Big)$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

Convergence of this series:  $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\Big(\frac{2x}{x+(n+5)^6}\Big)$$

x is from R

I tried different criteria and didn't get to an answer with none of them.

Comment: Hint: $|\sin(t)|\le|t|$ for $t\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $x,$ the general term is (eventually) very close to $\sin \left((n+5)^{-6}\right) \sim \frac1{(n+5)^6}.$ And since the series $\sum_{n} \frac1{(n+5)^6} $ converges by your favorite test, you are cooking with gas.

Comment: What does mean *"you are cooking with gas"* ? First time I read this expression. Thanks & cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It means that you are well-on your way to your goal :)

Comment: Thank you ! Nice expression